# Run function on load and resize & get height of class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have created this function but there are two things that are not working and, after a while trying to find why, I can't find the reason.

**First**, it should take the height from `.bar-info`, but is not. It gets -10, instead of 100px

**Second**, when the page loads (and on resize), it should run this function and get the height, but it doesn't. It works on resize, but not on ready

```
onResize = function() {
    if($(window).width() < 1000) {

        //Set height based in number of bars
        $('.vert .bars').each(function(){
            var length = $(this).find(".bar-info").length;
            var info = $(this).find(".bar-info").height();  // 1. Not taking the correct height

            var height =  (info * length) + 1270 + "px";
            $(this).parent().css({"height":height}); // 2. Wrong height just on load
        });

    } else {
        $('.vert .bars').each(function(){
            $(this).parent().css({"height":"1200px"});
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(onResize); // Why it doesn't work?
$(window).resize(onResize); // This works
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container vertical flat vert">
 <div class="bars">
    <div class="bar-general">
        <div class="bar-info">Content</div>
    </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could it be because `.resize` fires twice (start & end)?

Comment: @ScottMarcus where do you see the second? I just see this one: $(window).resize(onResize);

Comment: No, I mean the actual event triggers 2 times, once for the start of resize (at which point the final size hasn't been reached yet) and once when resize is complete (when sizes are final).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=resize+event+fires+twice&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS761US761&oq=resize+event+fires+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.5303j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: try changing `$(document).ready` with `$(window).on('load')`

Comment: Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ba2wj2su/). Hit "Run" and then resize the window. You will get two alerts with the count increasing between them.

Comment: @RajanBenipuri I had already tried that, but unfortunately it wasn't working either.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see... but I don't understand why is not running $(document).ready(onResize);